# Insert variable in Echo String

Tags: php, echo

I am using the following code to calculate the time difference between a post and the current time:

```
function format_interval(DateInterval $interval) {
            $result = "";
            if ($interval->y) { $result .= $interval->format("%y y "); }
            if ($interval->m) { $result .= $interval->format("%m m "); }
            if ($interval->d) { $result .= $interval->format("%d d "); }
            if ($interval->h) { $result .= $interval->format("%h h "); }
            if ($interval->i) { $result .= $interval->format("%i m "); }
            if ($interval->s) { $result .= $interval->format("%s s "); }

            return $result;
        }

        $first_date = new DateTime($row['updatecomment']);
        $second_date = new DateTime("now");

        $difference = $first_date->diff($second_date);

        $post_date = format_interval($difference);
```

I would then like to enter `$post_date` into the following echo string:

```
if ($row['comment'] != null) {
            echo '<div class="rowComment">' . '<div class="postComment" id="postcomment">' . $row['comment'] . '</div>' . '<div class="row3_a">' . "Posted: '.$post_date.' . Ago" . '</div>' . '</div>';
```

However, what I current get in return is:

```
Posted: '..' . Ago
```

I've searched the forums to get to this point. I feel I am very close, but I am just not getting the time difference output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few mismatched quotes.

```
if ($row['comment'] != null)
            echo '<div class="rowComment">' . '<div class="postComment" id="postcomment">' . $row['comment'] . '</div>' . '<div class="row3_a">' . "Posted: $post_date Ago" . '</div></div>';
```

Comment: that returns the following: Posted: Ago

Comment: That means that `$post_date` is an empty string.

Comment: hmm. when i remove the $post_date =  and echo the format_interval($difference); it returns the time difference. Can i enter format_interval($difference); into the echo string above instead of the variable?

Comment: That's odd, make sure that the variable is spelled correctly. Otherwise I guess you could do that, just pass `format_interval($difference)` instead of `$post_date`...

Comment: echo '<div class="rowComment">' . '<div class="postComment" id="postcomment">' . $row['comment'] . '</div>' . '<div class="row3_a">'."Posted: ".format_interval($difference)." Ago" . '</div>' . '</div>';